# Connecting Habitats Together?

Tags: planet-zoo

A bit of a vague title but to clarify, when placing barriers to make habitats, can one barrier be a partition between two habitats?

Does each habitat need its own distinct 'four walls` so if there were two habitats side by side there would be a small gap between the barriers. Or can I make one giant habitat then divide it in two by adding a single barrer down the middle?

Answer (score 1):

You can split up one habitat into two separate ones by adding a wall between them, sure. As in, they can share one or several walls in common. Each habitat needs exactly one door for keepers though or it won't function. Once split, they are regarded as separate with separate requirements.

Clicking on a wall shared between multiple habits won't immediately bring up the habitat menu, but you now get to chose which one the habits you are interested in first.

I strongly recommend to either move out any present animals or alternatively "box" them before doing radical changes to the habitat. Otherwise the game could get the idea that the animals have escaped and such.